# How to properly define containers in Singularity over different viewports

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, singularitygs

I gave Singularity a spin for a new project. So far i was using Susy. Normally i prefer to post the questions individually but in the present case the questions are connected dealing with one central point. The setting is the following.

My main page is a header with a background image and a footer with a gradient and the container with the content should be flanked by margins. The main markup skeleton looks like the following:

```
<div class="mainwrap">
  <header class="container"></header>
  <div class="container"></div>
</div>
<div class="footwrap">
  <footer class="container">
</div>
```

The basic styling of the wraps and containers looks like:

```
%wrap {
    width:100%;
    @extend %clearfix;
}

.mainwrap {
    @extend %wrap;
    background: image-url('texturetastic_gray.png') repeat top left;
    @include box-shadow(black 0.2em 0.2em 0.5em);
    margin-bottom:1em;
}
.footwrap {
    @extend %wrap;
    background-color: #484d51;
    @include background-image(linear-gradient(left, rgb(72, 77, 81), rgb(22, 25, 28)));
    @include filter-gradient(rgb(72, 77, 81), rgb(22, 25, 28), horizontal);
}

.container {
    @include background-grid;
    max-width:900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    @extend %clearfix;
}
```

Now i have two issues:

1) There are two gaps on the page

[image: The two gaps]

The first one is fixable with overflow-x: hidden; on %wrap or .mainwrap. But the second gap between .mainwrap and .footwrap isn't fixable with that. The desired look at the border between .mainwrap and .footwrap should look like the following. The footer visually underneath the mainwrap and the mainwrap has a visible dropshadow:

[image: Desired state]

But with the described html and css setup i get always the gap like already seen above:

[image: Present state with gap]

Any ideas why? :(

2) The setting of the container
That is the most uncertain part i have most of my issues with and ask myself what the best practice to handle might be. My basic settings are:

```
$grids: 4;
$grids: add-grid(6 at 550px);
$grids: add-grid(9 at 750px);
$grids: add-grid(12 at 900px);
$grids: add-grid(16 at 1200px);
$grids: add-grid(18 at 1400px);

$gutters:0.25;
$gutters: add-gutter(.20 at 900px);
$gutters: add-gutter(.15 at 1200px);
```

and for the .container i have added:

```
padding-left: gutter-span();
padding-right: gutter-span();
```

like suggested in one of the forum threads for Singularity on Github. But i am still uncertain what the best practice might be. Basically i would have a minimum padding which switches over to margin: 0 auto; when the defined maximum width for a container is reached. Is the way with the padding-left/right and gutter-span as well as the max-width the appropriate way?

Would that imply you have to define a basic column number and a max width for the container. When that max width is reached you change the max-width up and redefine the active grid setting with add-grid() and adjust the padding. You go on with that up until the maximum width of lets say 1400 or 1600px for the container is reacher. And on breakpoints for broader viewports you have to use multiples of gutter-span. Summed up it would look like e.g. that?

```
$grids: 4;
$grids: add-grid(8 at 600px);
$grids: add-grid(12 at 900px);
$grids: add-grid(16 at 1400px);

$gutters:0.25;
$gutters: add-gutter(.20 at 600px);
$gutters: add-gutter(.15 at 900px);
$gutters: add-gutter(.10 at 1400px);

.container {
    @include background-grid;
    max-width:600px;
    @include breakpoint(600px) {
        max-width: 900px;
    }
    @include breakpoint(900px) {
        max-width: 1400px;
    }
    @include breakpoint(1400px) {
        max-width: 1600px;
    }

    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: gutter-span();
    padding-right: gutter-span();
    @include breakpoint(600px) {
        padding-left: gutter-span(2);
        padding-right: gutter-span(2);
    }
    @include breakpoint(900px) {
        padding-left: gutter-span(3);
        padding-right: gutter-span(3);
    }
    @include breakpoint(600px) {
        padding-left: gutter-span(4);
        padding-right: gutter-span(4);
    }
    @extend %clearfix;
}
```

But basically that would lead to quite a few breakpoints if you wanna control things in a fine grained way on the container? Or is there a more elegant solution somehow?

Best regards Ralf

Comment: Can you please reduce your styles to only the ones relevant to the issue and then share them via http://sassbin.com ?

Comment: The sassbin gist for the gap issue in point one is there: http://sassbin.com/gist/7900290/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the second gap between .mainwrap and .footwrap isn't fixable with that. The desired look at the border between .mainwrap and .footwrap should look like the following. The footer visually underneath the mainwrap and the mainwrap has a visible dropshadow:

You've got `margin-bottom: 1em` applied to `.mainwrap`. Comment it out and you're good to go.

---

> i am still uncertain what the best practice might be. Basically i would have a minimum padding which switches over to margin: 0 auto; when the defined maximum width for a container is reached.

1. Why are you duplicating media queries? You could write both `max-width` and `padding` styles within the same `breakpoint` calls. But the matter is that you don't need to change the max-width. Set the max-width statically ONLY to the biggest maximum value.
2. You can have `max-width`, `padding` and `margin 0 auto` applied at the same time. No need to apply them selectively. Just be careful with which elements you apply those styles to.
3. If you're fine with static padding, e. g. `padding: 0 1em`, then you don't even need any breakpoints. If you need padding relative to the grid size, then don't hesitate to use breakpoints. If you feel they're bulky, create a mixin.

Comment: Argh i've overlooked the margin-bottom in .mainwrap. Thanks! Now the behaviour makes sense again. Initially i thought it was caused by my HTML markup in combination with Singularity. Shame on me ;) But about the whitespace flanking the content container and how to handle it, i am still not settled with and don't feel comfortable about. That the container remains "static" with e.g. padding: 0 1em till a max-width of e.g 1400px is reached feels off.

Comment: Considering that scenario if you try to keep a max characters per line count around 45 to 75 and you have a single column layout for e.g. a blog post you might get a long long line length. And thats the crux about my uncertainty with the definition of the whitespace margins and the container width changes from mobil up to desktop generally speaking. How tackle that elegantly.

Comment: And about your first point. I basically thought Sass and or Breakpoint would merge identical breakpoints within the same selector as one. But well i should better check the output on my own before expecting something like that. My bad. I will write them as one from now on. Thanks

Comment: @rpk "*about the whitespace flanking the content container*" - I don't see any extra vertical whitespace: http://sassbin.com/gist/7933564/ Do you mean something else?

Comment: @rpk "*Considering that scenario if you try to keep a max characters per line count around 45 to 75 and you have a single column layout for e.g. a blog post you might get a long long line length.*" Determine the width of a 75-character line and set max-width to that value.

Comment: In the gist there isn't any extra whitespace horizontally - i've reduced the gist example regarding the gap issue before i've posted it. Basically i've just meant the fact how to proceed in viewport width ranges where the max-width isn't reached yet. That you don't have to stick with the same thin flaking whitespace strips, on the left and right, you initially defined for your smallest basic viewport - but now you have to deal with them  on broader viewports as long as the max-width break isn't reached.

Comment: As you suggesd "Determine the width of a 75-character…" i guess i might try a two fold approach for the container. Till the max-width value is reached use the padding-left padding-right: gutter-span(); solution in one or two breakpoints and then set the max-width at an earlier point. Will have to try on the project page and then see how it works out on real content.